# Starting a fragment calls activity's onCreate()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an [AppCompatPreference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java) SettingsActivity with a PreferenceFragment, like this:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "activity onCreate called");
        setupActionBar();

        String userString = getIntent().getStringExtra(LoginActivity.USER);
        Log.v(TAG, "UserString: " + userString);

        ...
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d(TAG, "GeneralPreferenceFragment onCreate called");

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the app, a LoginActivity authenticates with a server and passes user data (userString) to the SettingsActivity.  It then starts a service with that data.

Everything is peachy and the service starts with no problem.

```
D/SettingsActivity: activity onCreate called
V/SettingsActivity: UserString: {some string of JSON user data}
```

But then I tap on `General Preferences`.  As soon as I do so, this gets logged:

```
D/SettingsActivity: activity onCreate called
V/SettingsActivity: UserString: null
```

Because it logs `activity onCreate called` instead of `GeneralPreferenceFragment onCreate called`, it seems like the wrong onCreate() is being called.  The app then crashes with a NullPointException trying to start the service with a null user.

I am trying to figure this out.  Maybe [the entire activity is restarting for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720118/does-fragment-call-the-oncreate-method-of-parent-activity#comment55210814_33720340)?  Any suggestions on diagnosing this problem would help.

Comment: Can you post the code where you handle click for your preference?

Comment: Sure.  I'm using the stock [AppCompatPreference activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).  In the pref_headers.xml, I have `<header android:fragment="com.mysite.myapp.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment" ... />`.

Comment: Where is the click handler code for when you click on `General Preferences`?

Comment: As far as I understand, the handler comes from the [`PreferenceFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html).  From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment): "Your implementation of PreferenceFragment can be as simple as defining the onCreate() method to load a preferences file with addPreferencesFromResource()".  I editted the post to include the `addPreferencesFromResource()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your log shows, a new instance of activity is created.

This is the expected behaviour of the `PreferenceActivity` on a phone. Tablets use a two-pane layout and keep a single activity. But phones start a new activity.

AppCompat behaves the same.

You can however pass more data to the fragment with

```
public class MySettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        super.onBuildHeaders(target);
        // You can build with xml settings that don't depend from UserString
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences, target);
        // For Settings that depend on UserString:
        Header userHeader = new Header();
        userHeader.title = ""; // TODO
        user.fragment = UserFragment.class;
        Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
        // TODO Pass a User parcelable instead
        args.putString(EXTRA_USER, userString);
        userHeader.fragmentArguments = args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that helps a lot!  The bounty is yours in three hours.  Do I really need to make a header to hold the userString?  I mean can't I just put it in the a bundle?  I was trying to put it in `savedInstanceState` but `onSaveInstanceState()` never got called.

Comment: Nevermind... I can just [save the logged in user as a SharedPreference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031837/android-keep-user-logged-in).

Comment: That's not correct. The "general" MySettingsActivity calls `onSaveInstanceState()` when the "account" MySettingsActivity is started.

Comment: There are of course different ways to pass the user, you can override your `Application` or an activity controller to have a current user. Saving it in a pref doesn't sound the best pattern (except if you want to remember this current user after a restart).